# How to store a credit-card-sized FPGA+CPU board?

Tags: pcb, fpga, storage

This might sound like a really dumb question, but I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to store a [Parallella board](https://www.parallella.org/) board that is always running a Linux server and is physically connected to a router.

Right now I've put it on top of a glass plate (plate, like the food kind) which admittedly "works" but is physically unsecured and therefore prone to falling off. And also ugly.

Ideally I would want to both (a) prevent the FPGA from accidentally touching something like paper or the carpet (it gets a little hot), and (b) prevent the whole circuit from accidentally touching something (due to static electricity or accidental shorts, etc.).

How do hobbyists store basic circuit boards like this? Do they just leave them on their desks or in some corner of the house with no type of enclosure? Or are there containers for this purpose? I can't even figure out what to search for since searching for "electronics trays" and things like that doesn't really show anything useful...

Comment: Put it in a box - any plastic enclosure will do - even a takeaway food tub. Make sure to add ventilation though.

Comment: I put unplugged components on a wooden desk, no plastics around, only coffee. Embedded boards are less static prone because the component are connected to a power supply.  I store them in their original boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Considering Adapteva themselves [offer](https://www.parallella.org/buy/) a 30$ case... go for that; it looks well-made.

Other than that: seriously, the PCB has four screw holes:

[image: PCB photo]

So get any enclosure you want, and put screw standoffs (the little things between your PC motherboard and PC case; everyone who's been building PCs should have a couple dozen laying around) and screw them into that case (drill holes in the right positions first).

If you want to leave the board out in the open, do so, by using just about any board (wood, PCB, steel, …) instead of an enclosure.

Comment: I didn't even realize they offered a case but I have to say that's very huge! I think they intended multiple boards to be in those? I don't build PCs so I don't actually know what enclosures to look for (do I search for "PCB enclosure"? or something else? the stuff that I can find is kind of oversized for this) but +1 for the ideas...

Comment: @Mehrdad - A typical set of kits: http://www.digikey.com/products/en/hardware-fasteners-accessories/board-spacers-standoffs/582